# how to access assets pipeline style in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

I have a style sheet file I put under "vendor" folder

vendor > assets > stylesheets > style.css

on my development machine if I try to access it with "/assets/style.css" I can.

In production it's not accessible. The styles on the page are broken:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/style.css")
```

Ideas how I can make that work?

Reason why I put it in Vendor is that I only wanted those style to be include in specific pages and not be compiled and included across the site, if there is a better way to include those assets only for specific pages please advise.

BTW, I'm deploying my app on Heroku.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access this in production you need to add that file to your precompile array in `application.rb`:

```
config.assets.precompile += ['styles.css']
```

You should reference the file in your view with the Rails' helpers:

```
stylesheet_link_tag('styles')
```

as this ensures the correct fingerprint is generated in the source.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the fact this stylesheet is in vendor path is a problem since sprockets should search in vendor too (from what I'm reading in the Asset Pipeline guide).

How do you try to access this CSS file? Have you tried to run

```
$rake assets:precompile
```

add/commit and re-push to Heroku remote?